# Not able to run basic azure function example in local

Tags: azure-functions

I am following the tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-maven-intellij

to run the basic example of an azure function in IntelliJ. I am getting the error

Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.6.0:run (default-cli) on project azure-function-examples: Stage directory not found. Please run mvn package first.

package org.example.functions;

This is the code of the function

```
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.ExecutionContext;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpMethod;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpRequestMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpResponseMessage;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.HttpStatus;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.AuthorizationLevel;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.FunctionName;
import com.microsoft.azure.functions.annotation.HttpTrigger;

import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * Azure Functions with HTTP Trigger.
 */
public class HttpTriggerFunction {
    /**
     * This function listens at endpoint "/api/HttpExample". Two ways to invoke it using "curl" command in bash:
     * 1. curl -d "HTTP Body" {your host}/api/HttpExample
     * 2. curl "{your host}/api/HttpExample?name=HTTP%20Query"
     */
    @FunctionName("HttpExample")
    public HttpResponseMessage run(
            @HttpTrigger(
                name = "req",
                methods = {HttpMethod.GET, HttpMethod.POST},
                authLevel = AuthorizationLevel.ANONYMOUS)
                HttpRequestMessage<Optional<String>> request,
            final ExecutionContext context) {
        context.getLogger().info("Java HTTP trigger processed a request.");

        // Parse query parameter
        final String query = request.getQueryParameters().get("name");
        final String name = request.getBody().orElse(query);

        if (name == null) {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body").build();
        } else {
            return request.createResponseBuilder(HttpStatus.OK).body("Hello, " + name).build();
        }
    }
}
```

Pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-function-examples</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Azure Java Functions</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>1.9.1</azure.functions.maven.plugin.version>
        <azure.functions.java.library.version>1.4.0</azure.functions.java.library.version>
        <functionAppName>logicapp-1617072939138</functionAppName>
        <stagingDirectory>${project.build.directory}/azure-functions/${functionAppName}</stagingDirectory>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.functions</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-functions-java-library</artifactId>
            <version>${azure.functions.java.library.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.23.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
                <artifactId>azure-functions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- function app name -->
                    <appName>${functionAppName}</appName>
                    <!-- function app resource group -->
                    <resourceGroup>java-functions-group</resourceGroup>
                    <!-- function app service plan name -->
                    <appServicePlanName>java-functions-app-service-plan</appServicePlanName>
                    <!-- function app region-->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-regions for all valid values -->
                    <region>westus</region>
                    <!-- function pricingTier, default to be consumption if not specified -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details#supported-pricing-tiers for all valid values -->
                    <!-- <pricingTier></pricingTier> -->

                    <!-- Whether to disable application insights, default is false -->
                    <!-- refers https://github.com/microsoft/azure-maven-plugins/wiki/Azure-Functions:-Configuration-Details for all valid configurations for application insights-->
                    <!-- <disableAppInsights></disableAppInsights> -->
                    <runtime>
                        <!-- runtime os, could be windows, linux or docker-->
                        <os>windows</os>
                        <javaVersion>8</javaVersion>
                        <!-- for docker function, please set the following parameters -->
                        <!-- <image>[hub-user/]repo-name[:tag]</image> -->
                        <!-- <serverId></serverId> -->
                        <!-- <registryUrl></registryUrl>  -->
                    </runtime>
                    <appSettings>
                        <property>
                            <name>FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION</name>
                            <value>~3</value>
                        </property>
                    </appSettings>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>package-functions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>package</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>${project.basedir}</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>host.json</include>
                                        <include>local.settings.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                        <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${stagingDirectory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                            <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                            <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                            <excludeArtifactIds>azure-functions-java-library</excludeArtifactIds>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!--Remove obj folder generated by .NET SDK in maven clean-->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>obj</directory>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

maven command:

```
azure-functions:package azure-functions:run
```

Answer (score 0):

***I have tried to reproduce the issue in my environment.***

Initially, I was getting the same error as shown below:

[image]

1. Later I have closed and re-opened IDE.
2. Ran below commands:

```
mvn azure-functions:package
mvn clean install
mvn azure-functions: run
```

Note: If it still gives error, close the IDE, reopen and run the command `mvn azure-functions:run`.
I could run the function locally in Intellij:

***Running `mvn azure-functions:package`:***

[image]

***mvn clean install:***
[image]

***Running `mvn azure-functions: run`:***

[image]

**Response:**

[image]

**Output:**
[image]